# typeerror e[Yn] is not a function component error salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, omnistudio

I already know that its about a flexcard, but i dont know why this behavior happens usually for some users.

```
typeerror e[Yn] is not a function component error salesforce

TypeError: e[Yn] is not a function
    at i (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs40/auraFW/javascript/wyQWsVjjDIx-Xsqekbsbwg/aura_prod.js:13:31891)
    at ae (https://orgunlimited--qa.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/0015400000whzWcAAI/modules/c/cfDataProtocol.js:1:4138)
    at https://static.lightning.force.com/cs40/auraFW/javascript/wyQWsVjjDIx-Xsqekbsbwg/aura_prod.js:13:35685
    at xe.observe (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs40/auraFW/javascript/wyQWsVjjDIx-Xsqekbsbwg/aura_prod.js:13:5714)
    at ar (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs40/auraFW/javascript/wyQWsVjjDIx-Xsqekbsbwg/aura_prod.js:13:34737)
    at Jr (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs40/auraFW/javascript/wyQWsVjjDIx-Xsqekbsbwg/aura_prod.js:13:40668)
    at mr (https://static.lightning.force.com/cs40/auraFW/javascript/wyQWsVjjDIx-Xsqekbsbwg/aura_prod.js:13:34633)
    at https://static.lightning.force.com/cs40/auraFW/javascript/wyQWsVjjDIx-Xsqekbsbwg/aura_prod.js:13:36504
```

Someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: You'll need to [Enable Debug Mode for Lightning Components](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aura_debug_mode.htm&type=5) for some users. When they next get the error, it should be a much more legible stack trace. Once you have that data, plus more info about whatever it was the user was doing, we can probably help you better.